# Variable in success: of Ajax which is running in a loop not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code, I'm running a for loop, which sets a variable 'nets' which is updated for each item within the array `netnos[]`.

Then I call Ajax to process a php to produce a listing, which **is correctly being output** to `response`.

I'm setting a variable `theList` inside the success function, which combines the `nets` variable with the response. Then appending to my subNets div.

The problem is the 'nets' variable here never updates from its original value, even thou the response is correct. This means the `data: {q : nets}` does changes correctly. 
So why is `nets` in the success: not being updated? It always retains the value of the first item in the array.

```
<script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.subnetkey', function() {
                var thelist = "";
                var strr   = $(".subnetkey").val();   // The string of net numbers like 789, 790
                var count  = strr.split(',').length;  // How many are in the string   2 in the test case
                var netnos = strr.split(",");         // The string made into an array of nets

                $("#subNets").removeClass("hidden");  // Remove the hidden from the subNets div

            for (i=0; i<count; i++) {                 // Loop through
                var nets = netnos[i];                 // Find each net number from the array
            // alert('i= '+i+' nets= '+nets); // When i=0 nets = 789, when i=1 nets = 790

                $.ajax({
                    type:    "GET",
                    url:     "getactivities.php",
                    data:    {q : nets},
                    success: function(response) {
                        var thelist = "#"+nets+"<br>"+response+"<br><br>";
                        $("#subNets").append(thelist);
                    },
                    error:   function() {
                        alert('Sorry no nets.');
                    }
                }) // End of ajax

              }  // End for loop

            }); // End of on(click) function
        }); // End of ready function
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the name `nets` is lexically bound in the for loop, and its value will change as you iterate `i`. An easy way to fix this is to use `Array.forEach` as each invocation of the function it uses for iteration will have its own binding of `nets` - and it'll lead to shorter code too as you don't even need `i`!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".subnetkey", function() {
    var strr = $(".subnetkey").val();
    var netnos = strr.split(",");

    $("#subNets").removeClass("hidden");
    netnos.forEach(nets => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getactivities.php",
        data: { q: nets },
        success: function(response) {
          var thelist = "#" + nets + "<br>" + response + "<br><br>";
          $("#subNets").append(thelist);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Sorry no nets.");
        },
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't completely understand this, especially the "lexically bound in the for loop" but it works. I'll study this to understand for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Define your nets variable like this and it should work

```
let nets = netnos[i];
```